# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "azurefileshare" : Couldn't get secret default

Tags: azure-aks, docker-volume, windows-container, azure-files, azure-secrets

Hi I am trying to mount azure file share to windows container. My node Pool kubernetes version is 119.9.
I have added secrete as below in my release pipeline as first step

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: storage-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  azurestorageaccountname: base64accountname
  azurestorageaccountkey: base64accountkey
```

In second step I have below code

```
volumeMounts:
        - name: azurefileshare
          mountPath: Z:\    
volumes:
      - name: azurefileshare
        azureFile:
          secretName: storage-secret
          shareName: share
          readOnly: false
```

After deployment I see below error

> MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "azurefileshare" : Couldn't get
> secret default/storage-secret

I am trying to find out the root cause but not able to find what is wrong here. Can someone help me to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just upgraded from AKS 1.17 to 1.19. It was working fine in 1.17, not sure what's to be changed in 1.19.

Comment: Looks like you shouldn't encode in base64 anymore.